# Split() in flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, split

```
{Country: [Local, Chinese, Indian, Italy, Thai]}
{Meals: [Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner]}
```

I need to split this String value and get the first word like "Country", "Meals".

Comment: You mean the key of the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is using the .split():

```
String mealsMap = '{Meals: [Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner]}';
String newMealsMap = mealsMap.replaceAll(RegExp(r"[^\s\w]"), "");

print(newMealsMap.split(' ')[0]); // returns Meals
```

Comment: Thank you but it complicated.

Comment: @Geethma The newMealsMap is using a function replaceAll to go through the entire mealsMap string and replace any non alphabet characters with an empty string (so removing them). Then newMealsMap.split('  ')[0] is just splitting the text of newMealsMap and separating them whenever it finds a space in the text and storing each word as a list of strings, then calling [0] gets the first string. I hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var ogString = "{Country: [Local, Chinese, Indian, Italy, Thai]}";
 var modifiedString = ogString.split(":")[0].substring(1); //Country
```

maybe this might help

Answer (score 0):

You should decode the json into a usable Map like so:

Import the json library

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

Then decode your string:

```
json.decode(jsonString)
```

Then you will have a map that looks like this:

```
 Map<String, List<String>> x = {
      'Country': ['Local', 'Chinese', 'Indian', 'Italy', 'Thai'],
      'Meals': ['Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Dinner']
  };
```

You can loop through the Map keys like so:

```
for (String key in x.keys) {
   print(key); // This will be Country or Meals
}
```

Or use another method from the `x.keys` type `Iterable<String>` to match a given key like:

```
x.keys.firstWhere((String key) => key == 'Country');
```

Hope this can be of help.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps,

1. You can convert the JSON to an object first.
2. Then loop over the object and print the keys one by one.

```
    var obj = jsonDecode(yourJson); //#1 - import "dart:convert" 

    for (var key in obj.keys) //#2
    {
       print(key); //#2
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you trying to do Split int from string you can do following

```
String exampleVariable = "127 km";
print("XCD " + fixdKmsSplit.split('km').toString());
//output: XCD [127,]

print("XCD " + fixdKmsSplit.split('km')[0].toString());
//output: XCD 127
```